# iPhone - How may I know if an URL is a resource file?

Tags: iphone, url, resources, uiwebview, request

I'm catching an url in shouldStartLoadWithRequest.

How may I know if it's one of my project resources that is trying to be opened (for example with `[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlContentFinal baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath]];`), or something else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if URL string starts with `file://`:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (request.URL.isFileURL) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

---

> How may I ensure that I am the one who loaded that file? The user could wrote that url in the url field himself.

You can implement `-textFieldDidBeginEditing` or `-textFieldDidEndEditing` and set some boolean properties to `YES`:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([[textField.text substringToIndex:7] isEqualToString:@"file://"]) {
        self.fileUrlEnteredManually = YES;
    } else {
        self.fileUrlEnteredManually = NO;
    }
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (request.URL.isFileURL) {
        if (self.fileUrlEnteredManually) {
            // user entered "file://" manually
        } else {
            // user didn't
        }
    }
}

- (void)viewDidload {

    // ...

    fileUrlEnteredManually = NO;
    [webView loadRequest:yourLocalRequest];

}
```

Comment: How may I ensure that I am the one who loaded that file ? The user could wrote that url in the url field himself.

Comment: Does user use UITextField to enter the url?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `[URL schema]`. If it's `file`, then it's a local file. It won't be necessarily a bundle resource, though - could be a file in your app's Documents, for example.

To make sure it's in the bundle, match the beginning of the path with the bundle's path, available from the [NSBundle mainBundle]. Although I don't see why.

Comment: How may I ensure that I am the one who loaded that file ? The user could wrote that url in the url field himself.

Comment: @Oliver: Why do you have an URL field if you don't want users loading arbitrary URLs? The content of your resource folder is known to you at design time; if that's the only content you want to make available, instead of a freeform URL field, provide a list (`UITableView` or something) of valid resources.

Comment: I want to make a freeform URL available, but I want to ensure the user won't try to enter files URL from the iPhone.

Comment: @Oliver: Validate user input URLs *before* they get into WebView.